# In R, given y = f(x), how do I find the global max of y/x?

Tags: r, maximize

I have created a curve that shows for each level of spend (X) a unique output in revenue (Y).

The curve is defined by the following (monotone) function:

```r
calculate_abc_revenue <- function(a, b, c, spend) {

  res <- ifelse(
    a/(1+b*(spend)^c) >= 0,
    a/(1+b*(spend)^c),
    0
    )

  return(res)

}
```

Where `a`, `b` and `c` are given parameters and should be treated as constant:

```r
a0 <- 1303066.36937866
b0 <- 15560519.9999999
c0 <- -1.09001859302511
```

Now, if we define ROI as:

```r
revenue <- calculate_abc_revenue(a = a0, b = b0, c = c0, spend)
ROI <- revenue/spend
```

How do I find the exact values of `revenue` and `spend` that make `ROI` max?

I currently use a spend vector of length n that helps me finding **approximately** the max ROI, but most of the times the result is not 100% exact as the *real max ROI* can fall between two points sent as input.

I would like to avoid to increase the length of the spend vector as it would increase the calculation time (and it wouldn't guarantee that the solution found is a global max anyway).

Comment: Use `optim` .....

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Roland, would you mind helping me setting the solution for this?

Comment: Isn't  your function monotonically increasing?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @MarBlo. Not necessarily (it can happen, but it can also flatten) but it doesn't really matter. The important thing is that even if it keeps increasing, what we want to maximise is the value of y divided by x.

Comment: as a tangent, you don't need an ifelse.  You can just do `pmax(0, a/(1+b*(spend)^c))`

Comment: also, I don't think numerical optimizers can strictly guarantee a *global* max but that's a math issue not a programming one.

Comment: When  `f(x)` has a closed form, as it does here,  just take the derivative of the new function `g(x) = f(x)/x`   .   You can solve this analytically so far as I can tell from your description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting `ROI` as a function, we can use `optimize`:

```
ROI <- function(spend) calculate_abc_revenue(a0, b0, c0, spend)/spend

optspend <- optimize(ROI, c(0, 1e12), maximum = TRUE)$maximum
c("optimal spend" = optspend, revenue = calculate_abc_revenue(a0, b0, c0, optspend))
#> optimal spend       revenue 
#>      435274.1      107613.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach. It uses `unitroot` applied to the derivative of the ROI-function `f`. (only valid for `spend > 0`)
From this function the derivative is build from which a function is created. This function is then fed into `unitroot`.

Plots in the upper row show ROI over a wide range of investment and its derivative. The lower row shows a zoomed version of those.

```
#| function related to investment (spend) ROI
f = expression(1 / spend * (a0 / (1 + b0 * spend^c0)))     

#| get the derivative
ff_2 <- D(f, 'spend')
#| uniroot
ff_2 <- function(spend){}
body(ff_2) <- ff
res <- uniroot(ff_2, c(1e5, 1e6))
c("optimal spend" = res$root, revenue = calculate_abc_revenue(spend = res$root))
# optimal spend       revenue 
#    435274.1      107613.0
```

[image]

---

Original Data

```
a0 <- 1303066.36937866
b0 <- 15560519.9999999
c0 <- -1.09001859302511

#| Original function
calculate_abc_revenue <- function(a = a0,b = b0, c = c0,spend) {
  res <- ifelse(
    a/(1+b*(spend)^c) >= 0,
    a/(1+b*(spend)^c),
    0
  )
  return(res)
}
```

Comment: The plot of ROI vs Investment is very useful - I will probably consider the use of it for internal purposes, thanks @MarBlo!